# Azure, keep site up to do regular batch job

Tags: node.js, azure

I've deployed an app on Azure. If no visits it for 20minutes, it goes down and is fired up again when a persons visits it.

It's a problem since I have a regular batch job on the backend (node js)

```
  schedule.scheduleJob("0 16 23 * * *", () => {
    fetchAndStoreData();
  });
```

If the site is down at this time, the job is not firing.

Is there any automatic way I can make sure the site is up at this time? Price to upgrade is crazy high so I don't want to pay.

Ofcourse I could schedule som curl job from another server but I would prefer If I could keep isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you configure Always on in your App Service:

[image]

Or you create a Web Job:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

And last option is that you setup a web test that will query your site every 5 minute and keep the site active.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

Comment: Is there any non-microsoft-way of doing this? Can't I just add something in my nodejs-code?

Comment: @Joe no since its default IIS behaviour to shutdown after 20 minutes you need to force it in someway to stay active. Last option I provided is probably the easiest and cheapest. Just create a web test that pings the site every 5 second, that will keep it alive without you have to scale up the web app.